# finding the median of a PDF with r

Tags: r, function, math

so i was messing around in r and i was trying to make a function that finds the mean, variance and median (also possibly bounds) of a function. i've been able to get the mean and variance working but i am i don't know how to make the median as-well as defining 2 sets of bounds so that the intergral of my function = 1 (given either a starting or end point of the bounds)

Here is the function so far

```
dense <- function(lower1=0,upper1,f=function(x)x, uppertail = F ){
      
    xf<-function(x){
      return(x*f(x))
    }
    
      
    xxf<-function(x){
      return(x*x*f(x))
    }
    
  if(uppertail == F){
    
    m0f<-integrate(f,lower=lower1,upper = upper1)
    m1f<-integrate(f = xf ,lower=lower1,upper = upper1) 
    m2f<-integrate(xxf ,lower=lower1,upper = upper1) 
    
   v <-(m2f$value)-(m1f$value)^2
    return(paste("variance =",v,"mean/expected = ",m1f$value,"intergral = ",m0f$value))
      
  }else{ 
      integrate(f=f,lower=upper1,upper = lower1)
    
    m0f<-integrate(f,lower=upper1,upper = lower1)
    m1f<-integrate(f = xf ,lower=upper1,upper = lower1) 
    m2f<-integrate(xxf ,lower=upper1,upper = lower1) 
      
     v <-(m2f$value)-(m1f$value)^2

    return(paste("variance =",v,"mean/expected = ",m1f$value,"intergral = ",m0f$value))

  }
}
```

in know how to solve it on paper but i'd like to figure out how to make r do it for me

(to solve on paper for median you set the intergeral = 0.5)
(and for bounds you'd set the value of you're intergral = 1)

i am just trying to test it with the "pdf" f(x)= x , from 0 to x , 0 otherwise

i have thought of doing it as a while loop but that seems rather computationally intense
(i.e adding 0.0000000001 to the end bounds of my intergral until it = 1)
and also prone to failure

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you need - I assume you're looking for the integration limit that sets your integral to 0.5. You can solve for that using e.g. `uniroot` (or `optim`/`optimize`, but the cumulative density should be nice & monotone). You subtract whatever value you're looking for to make that the zero point.

Comment: Depends a lot on what you can assume about your function. Is it vectorized? Do you know if it has an upper bound? Is it continuous? What happens if you exceed the bounds - is there an error? I could define a function that has any arbitrary upper bound, `1`, or `234.21` or `8.537e12`. Finding it by increments isn't a good strategy.

Comment: If you can assume continuity you could try out a sequence like `10^(1:100)` and then do additional rounds of sampling to get as much precision as you'd like. But it seems kinda pointless.

Comment: @Gregor Thomas
 i realize that finding it by increments is not a good strategy but if my function where to have a small error that would be okay  (assume the function would always be bounded and continuous on the bounded region. if its not in the bounds the function = 0)

Comment: @PBulls thanks that helped me find the median sorry i should have read yours sooner

Comment: So then you need to find the bounded region. The question is what assumptions can you make about the bounded region. If you can assume the function is friendly enough that the bounded region is more likely to be "close" to 0, than far from it, by which I mean more likely to be in, say, -10^6 to 10^6 than from 10^12 to 10^13 (even though the second region is much larger), then I think a logarithmic-scaled search like I proposed would be a reasonably starting place. Evaluate the function at `x = c(-10^(12:1), 10^0:12)`, assess where you have non-zero values, and resample accordingly.

Comment: Of course, good luck finding my function `foo = \(x) ifelse(x < 576284182.1 | x > 576284182.2, 0, 10)`, but that's not a function with friendly bounds.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of `integrate` and `uniroot`, but it is necessary to define both the lower and upper limits:

```r
find_median <- function(fun, lower, upper) {
  uniroot(function(x) integrate(fun, lower, x)$value - 0.5, 
          c(lower, upper), tol = .Machine$double.eps)$root |> round(9)
}

find_median(function(x) x, 0, 2)
#> [1] 1

find_median(dnorm, -10, 10)
#> [1] 0

find_median(dunif, 0, 1)
#> [1] 0.5
```

It might be possible to give arbitrary default values for `lower` and `upper`, but one needs to be careful that the number of subdivisions in `integrate` is sufficiently high to find the non-zero domain of your function. There are lots of gotchas here depending on the function, but this solution will handle most pdfs with sensible inputs just fine.